# Rails4 Javascript Auto refresh selected Div and render chart instead of spewing html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

Hi i'm new and I've been super stuck at this javascript problem. I've been searching for a solution but I can't seem to get it to work properly.

In my app/views/layouts/application.html.erb i've placed the following

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>EUR VS USD</title>

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "//code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js", "chartkick" %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'http://yandex.st/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'http://yandex.st/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js' %>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    // get data every 5 seconds and refresh myDiv
    var pingAfter = 5000;  
    var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
        $("#firstchart").load('/welcome/firstchart');
    }, pingAfter);
});
</script>

  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

The initial page loads fine, until the refresh 5secs later which results in the html code of the #div being spewed instead of the chart. how can I get the chart to load instead of the code spew.

Initial page load -  https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WIor.png
After auto refresh - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wy1ca.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That endpoint is returning JSON, you need to parse the contents of `div_contents` > `div#container` to update your div element with the HTML content.

UPDATE:

Try this:

```
  var pingAfter = 5000;
  var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
    $.getJSON( "/welcome/firstchart", function(data) {
      $('#firstchart').html(data.div_contents['div#container']);
    });
  }, pingAfter);
```

Comment: Thanks tirdadc, could you point me to where I can find out how to do that?